# Can't find Configuration Property in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, properties, configuration, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to use `gcd` function from `#include <numeric>` in Visual Studio 2019 (Community version). However, using `namespace std`, visual studio just says that "gcd" is undefined. Based on my research, I'm supposed to change the C++ version. However, in the normal settings I can't find "Configuration Properties" and right clicking on the project in the solution explorer to then select properties, just shows me an empty window (see [emtpy-property-window picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DURdy.png)).

**Background info:**

- Created project with C++ (Cmake Project) in Visual Studio 2019 Community
- Added a C++ file (.cpp) with main function and one class
- For Building I'm using Cmake
- Using `namespace std` and `#inlcude <iostream>` so far (with no problem)
- When using `#include <numeric>` and then trying to use `gcd(x,y)`, I get the previous described error-hint
- Visual Studio tries to fix the error with adding `namespace std`, even though that's already added.

Any idea to solve either problem?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can test.  Did you install the C++ workspace as it's not installed by default ?  What project type did you create ?

Comment: I added further information as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`gcd` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) was added in C++17. You probably haven't set the appropriate standard in your project settings. At least this is the exact issue you'll get when trying to use `std::filesystem::...` with an older C++ standard with Visual Studio. (The file system library was added in C++17 too.)

In the project properties `Configuration Properties` > `General` > `C++ Language Standard` should be set to `ISO C++17 Standard (/std::c++17)` to make the code compile.

You can open the project properties by selecting `Properties` in the context menu for the target shown in the solution explorer btw; the properties shown in your screenshot just display some very basic information about the selected item.

Comment: Thanks fabian for your answer. I did know that I probably had to adjust that but it wouldn't show me the Configuration Properties. However I realized now that I created a "Cmake Project". When I create an "Empty Project", it does show me all the correct properties and as you expected it, it was set to 2014 version by default.

Comment: @Scorpia When creating a VS solution from a `CMakeLists.txt` file, you should be able to do `set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)`; Not sure if this is the same when creating a CMake project directly from Visual Studio though; I only remember the last time I tried creating a cmake project via VS wizard, the resulting project was borderline unuseable...

Comment: I did not know that but now I do, thanks.